# How do I remove a subset of items from a knockout collection based on an existing collection

Tags: knockout.js

Am a newbie in Knockout.js.

```
function UniqueCustomerViewModel(dataFromServer){
    self.customerMasterList = ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.CustomerList)));
    self.chosenCustomerList = ko.observableArray(dataFromServer.Customer.ChosenCustomers);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(chosenCustomerList(), function (customerRow) {
        self.customerMasterList.remove(customerRow);
    });
    // ...
}
```

Getting error: 0x800a138a - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Function expected on the line ko.utils.arrayForEach

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Interesting error. Could you add a breakpoint on `ko.utils.arrayForEach` and see if it's really a function?

Comment: yes, it is a function.

Comment: have you tried the answer? If it worked, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I've found the problem, you missed `self` for `chosenCustomerList`:

```
...
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.chosenCustomerList(), function (customerRow) {
    self.customerMasterList.remove(customerRow);
});
...
```

As for removing elements - you might have to find element in self.customerMasterList() first if it's not some plain type and then remove it. Like this:

```
...
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.chosenCustomerList(), function (customerRow) {
    var customer = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.customerMasterList(), function(item) {
        return item.id === customerRow.id; // or something like thatt
    });
    if (customer)
        self.customerMasterList.remove(customer);
});
...
```